# Capturing first 4 and last 4 chars from a string in Bash?

Tags: bash

I have the following string,

```
szTemp="23.4 78.9"
```

I want to split it into two smaller strings,

```
szIndoorTemp="23.4"
szOutdoorTemp="78.9"
```

However doing this,

```
szIndoorTemp=${szTemp::-5}
szOutdoorTemp=${szTemp::5}
```

Does not produce this and causes the script to crash. 
In addition, when I do

```
echo $szTemp
```

I get

```
23.4
78.9
```

I suspect that this may mean that there is a carriage return in the string.

**Update**
This may be close...

```
#!/bin/bash

szTemps="23.4 67.8"

szIndoorTemp=${szTemps:0:4}
szOutdoorTemp=${szTemps:5}

echo $szIndoorTemp
echo $szOutdoorTemp
```

Comment: Even if there's a CR in the string, since you didn't quote the variable it will be treated as a word separator, and won't be echoed literally.

Comment: _"and causes the script to crash"_  Show us the __complete exact__ error message.

Comment: _"I suspect that this may mean that there is a carriage return in the string."_  If you defined it as shown in your question, then there is __no__ carriage return.  If you defined it differently, then show us the code that you are actually using.

Comment: Showing us code that you are __not__ using is not helpful.  You need to create a [mcve] and show us that example.

Comment: If your shell exits, try starting a new shell with `bash`  and maybe set `PS1=\$` to clearly see when it has exited, and then run the crashing script inside this subshell, perhaps with `bash -x`. To see any special characters in the input string, try `cat -v`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than depend on exact number of characters, I would go with relying on the space as a separator:

```
read szIndoorTemp szOutdoorTemp <<< "$szTemp"
```

As an alternative, you could do:

```
read szIndoorTemp szOutdoorTemp < <(yourPythonScript)
```

Comment: The Python script that produces szTemp gives me a string that will echo as "12.3 45.6", however when I run your solution I get szIndoorTemp = "12.3" and szOutdoorTemp="".  I have tried szTemp=${szTemp//$'\n'/} as well as for '\r' and '\t' with no luck. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I wonder if you are correctly quoting your capture, I have added an alternative method above.

Answer (score 1):

I think if I am getting it right here `-5` could be the culprit, when I run command mentioned by you I see following error:

```
szIndoorTemp=${szTemp::-5}
bash: -5: substring expression < 0
```

But when I change from `-5` to `5` it flies as follows:

```
szIndoorTemp=${szTemp::5}
echo $szIndoorTemp
23.4
```

Comment: I can only reproduce the error that you see if `$szTemp` is short.  Using the `szTemp` defined as per the OP's question, it works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for the response(s). szTemp is the output of a Python script. However, defining szTemp with known chars, "12.3 45.6" results in echo $szTemp producing output that does not wrap, but if I uncomment szIndoorTemp=${szTemp::5}...it crashes, (terminal window collapses) when I run it. OS is Raspian. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this...

$ cat example.sh 

szTemp="23.4 78.9"
echo "szIndoorTemp=${szTemp:0:4}"
echo "szOutdoorTemp=${szTemp:(-4)}"

$ sh example.sh 

szIndoorTemp=23.4
szOutdoorTemp=78.9



You can also try this, if it works for you..

$ cat example.sh

szTemp="23.4 78.9"
szarray=($szTemp)
echo "szIndoorTemp=${szarray[0]}"
echo "szOutdoorTemp=${szarray[1]}"


$ sh example.sh 

szIndoorTemp=23.4
szOutdoorTemp=78.9
```

Answer (score -1):

I use filter, a function in my ~/.bashrc, because I need it so often, that the simple awk-solution is too complicated for me:) :

```
echo "23.4 78.9" | filter 1 2
23.4    78.9
```

And filter picks arguments in specified order by their index, counting from 1:

```
filter () 
{ 
    declare -a arr;
    while read val; do
        arr=($val);
        for param in "$@";
        do
            echo -n -e ${arr[$param-1]} "\t";
        done;
        echo;
    done
}
```

Usage:

```
echo "23.4 78.9" | filter 1
23.4
echo "23.4 78.9" | filter 2
78.9
```

The equivalent operation in awk is:

```
echo $szTemp | awk '{print "$1"}'
23.4
echo $szTemp | awk '{print "$2"}'
78.9
```

but the curly braces are hard to type on a German keyboard; I guess we have the äüöß characters, where English keyboards have `{` and `}`.

Variable assignment becomes:

```
first=$(echo "23.4 78.9" | filter 1)
23.4
second=$(echo "23.4 78.9" | filter 2)
78.9
```

Comment: Your `filter` function is just unsafely implementing the `cut` command.

Comment: @chepner: AFAIK you can't cut fields in arbitrary sequence, like my `echo "a b c d e f" | filter 4 3 2 → d c b`. What do you consider unsafe?

Comment: The unquoted parameter expansion `($val)` will not work as expected if any part of `$val` is a glob that matches files in the current directory. (I did miss, though, that the output of `cut` is in the order of appearance of the input, regardless of the order of the fields in the `-f` argument. `-f 4,3,2` and `-f 2,3,4` are equivalent.)

Comment: @chepner: So what do you suggest? I have to admit that I'm not used to set or unset globbing and my first attempts now failed miserably. Can I set/unset these in my function? I tried 'shopt -s globstar; shopt -s dotglob in the function and before calling it.` Shouldn't the user control which globbings should be interpreted and which not?